# How to find out namespace of a particular process?

Tags: linux, process, namespace

I already asked a question about [how to list all namespaces in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105403/22565), but there wasn't any correct and exact answers, so I want to find out a method which can help me to find out the namespace of PID of some process or group of processes. How can it be done in Linux?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'll try and answer both this and [your earlier question](/q/105403) as they are related.

The doors to namespaces are files in `/proc/*/ns/*` and `/proc/*/task/*/ns/*`.

A namespace is created by a process [*unsharing*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html) its namespace. A namespace can then be made permanent by *bind-mounting* the `ns` file to some other place.

That's what `ip netns` does for instance for *net* namespaces. It unshares its `net` namespace and bind-mounts `/proc/self/ns/net` to `/run/netns/netns-name`.

In a `/proc` mounted in the root pid namespace, you can list all the namespaces that have a process in them by doing:

```
# readlink /proc/*/task/*/ns/* | sort -u
ipc:[4026531839]
mnt:[4026531840]
mnt:[4026531856]
mnt:[4026532469]
net:[4026531956]
net:[4026532375]
pid:[4026531836]
pid:[4026532373]
uts:[4026531838]
```

The number in square brackets is the inode number.

To get that for a given process:

```
# ls -Li /proc/1/ns/pid
4026531836 /proc/1/ns/pid
```

Now, there may be *permanent* namespaces that don't have any process in them. Finding them out can be a lot trickier AFAICT.

First, you have to bear in mind that there can be several *mount* namespaces.

```
# awk '$9 == "proc" {print FILENAME,$0}' /proc/*/task/*/mountinfo | sort -k2 -u
/proc/1070/task/1070/mountinfo 15 19 0:3 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - proc proc rw
/proc/19877/task/19877/mountinfo 50 49 0:3 / /run/netns/a rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:2 - proc proc rw
/proc/19877/task/19877/mountinfo 57 40 0:3 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - proc proc rw
/proc/1070/task/1070/mountinfo 66 39 0:3 / /run/netns/a rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:2 - proc proc rw
/proc/19877/task/19877/mountinfo 68 67 0:3 / /mnt/1/a rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime unbindable - proc proc rw
```

Those `/mnt/1/a`, `/run/netns/a` may be namespace files.

We can get an inode number:

```
# nsenter --mount=/proc/19877/task/19877/ns/mnt -- ls -Li /mnt/1/a
4026532471 /mnt/1/a
```

But that doesn't tell us much other than it's not in the list computed above.

We can try and enter it as any of the different types:

```
# nsenter --mount=/proc/19877/task/19877/ns/mnt -- nsenter --pid=/mnt/1/a true
nsenter: reassociate to namespace 'ns/pid' failed: Invalid argument
# nsenter --mount=/proc/19877/task/19877/ns/mnt -- nsenter --mount=/mnt/1/a true
nsenter: reassociate to namespace 'ns/mnt' failed: Invalid argument
# nsenter --mount=/proc/19877/task/19877/ns/mnt -- nsenter --net=/mnt/1/a true
#
```

OK, that was a `net` namespace file.

So it would seem we have a method to list the name spaces: list the `ns` directories of all the tasks, then find all the `proc` mountpoints in all the `/proc/*/task/*/mountinfo` and figure out their type by trying to enter them.

Comment: "A namespace is created by a process unsharing its namespace." Is there any meaning in the word "unshared" here? For me "unshare" means "make private".

Comment: @Student4K, see `man 2 unshare` and `man 1 unshare`.

Answer (score 31):

If you have **util-linux v2.28 or above** you can use **lsns**:

```
# lsns
        NS TYPE  NPROCS   PID USER             COMMAND
4026531836 pid       78     1 root             /sbin/init
4026531837 user      79     1 root             /sbin/init
4026531838 uts       78     1 root             /sbin/init
4026531839 ipc       78     1 root             /sbin/init
4026531840 mnt       75     1 root             /sbin/init
4026531857 mnt        1    12 root             kdevtmpfs
4026531957 net       79     1 root             /sbin/init
4026532393 mnt        1  1214 root             /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
4026532415 mnt        1  2930 systemd-timesync /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
4026532477 mnt        1 32596 root             -bash
4026532478 uts        1 32596 root             -bash
4026532479 ipc        1 32596 root             -bash
4026532480 pid        1 32596 root             -bash
```

Correction: lsns is not available in util-linux v2.27 as this answer used to say. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.28/v2.28-ReleaseNotes

Comment: There's also a nice python script I found, for those on older linux. http://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=251

Comment: `lsns` is very useful but it only shows the lowest PID in each namespace - i.e. it can't tell you the namespace for any arbitrary PID.  +1 anyway because this is still a useful answer even if it doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 20):

`ps` now has output options for the different types of namespaces associated with processes: `ipcns`, `mntns`, `netns`, `pidns`, `userns`, and `utsns`.  For this question, the relevant one is the PID namespace, or `pidns`.

so if you wanted to find out the PID namespace id for, e.g., pid 459:

```
# ps -h -o pidns -p 459
4026532661
```

and to list all processes in that namespace:

```
ps -o pidns,pid,cmd | awk '$1==4026532661'
```

or with `pgrep`, you can go directly from a PID to a list of all processes sharing that same PID namespace:

```
pgrep -a --ns 459
```

Unlike `ps`, `pgrep` can limit the output to a specific namespace (if you know the PID of one of the processes in it), but has very limited output formatting capabilities (PIDs only, or PIDs and their command lines)

You can always pipe the output of `pgrep --ns 459` to `xargs ps -f` though to retrieve the information you need about the process.

Comment: Unfortunately I noticed that in a system derived from RHEL 7.4 with procps-ng version 3.3.10 (Check Point Gaia R80.40, RPM: procps-ng-3.3.10-16.el7.cp994000011.i686) `ps` wrongly shows inode numbers of namespaces as signed int32. You can convert them to uint32 in bash using this expression: `$(($inode & 0xffffffff))`.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ ip netns identify $PID
```

where `$PID` is the I.D. of the process, which you can get in various ways.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html

Comment: Note that it's only for network namespaces and only ones created using `ip netns` (or at least created by something that bind-mounts the namespace doors in /run/netns like `ip netns` does). It basically looks in /run/netns for files that are the same as  `/proc/$PID/ns/net`.

Comment: What? `/run/netns` doesn't even exist on my computer.

Comment: `/run/netns` or wherever `ip` bind-mounts the namespace special files. `findmnt -t nsfs` may  tell you where it is on your system. OTOH, if you do `unshare -n sleep 1000 & ip netns identify "$!"`, you won't get anything.

Comment: `findmnt -t nsfs` - nothing. `unshare -n sleep 1000 & ip netns identify "$!"` - unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: You need superuser privileges (CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) to create a new netns. `findmnt -t nsfs` returning nothing suggests that you don't have any netns on your machine ATM.

Comment: Ah yes, running as root stops the complaint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**[Namespace-Lister](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Namespace-Lister):**

You can use **[listns.py](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Namespace-Lister)**

Usage: `./listns.py` or `python2 listns.py` To answer precisely this question, you can grep the result like this `python2 listns.py | grep $PID` (replace the pid variable)

*Source: [github-mirror](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Namespace-Lister) and [article](https://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=251)* *all credit to [Ralf Trezeciak](https://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=251)*

**[Network namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html):**

For network namespace,`ip netns identify $PID` can be used.

**[Nsutils](https://github.com/rd235/nsutils)**

Provide `pidnslist` that return the pid namespace of a process

```
$ pidnslist -ss 8782
pid:[4026531836]
```