# How to move process from one namespace to other?

Tags: linux, process, lxc, namespace

This question is similar to my question about [how to list namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113530/how-to-find-out-namespace-of-a-particular-process). So in addtition, I'd like to know some information about moving processes from one namespace to other? E.g. I have processes of current session in one namespace and some other processes of `lxc` container in different namespace, so I want to run (e.g. `links`) in cgroup of that container (it's easily do with `cgexec`) and then move it to container's namespace , because I have to run this process in container without executing it exact in it. Can it be done or it's impossible in Linux??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run process in some control groups if you already in certain namespace, instead you have to manipulate with namespaces. All new process in new namespace will «inherit» all control groups related to that namespace.

Moving processes between different namespaces can be done with [setns()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html) function or you can use [nsenter](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) command from `util-linux` to enter new namespace and then run new tasks in it. All you need is to know PID of process, which already is new namespace, then you can use (in case you want to run `links`):

```
# nsenter --PID --target pid_in_ns_you_want_to_enter && links
```

It's some cheat, because you don't moving processes, you just entered in namespace and running new processes, but with this possibility you can enter in certain NS and then `fork` in it already running in other NS process.

Comment: Is there anything that allows calling `setns` from bash, and moving a particular process by their ID to a namespace?

Comment: `setns` seems to be completely useless: "A multithreaded process may not change user namespace with setns()", "A process may not be reassociated with a new mount namespace if it is multithreaded"