# How to keep the kernel from accessing the journal on an ext4 partition?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, ext4, journaling

I hope that this is not a duplicate question. I have seen several similar questions, where the answer was to blacklist the respective device or partition. But in my case, I can't do that (see below). Having said this:

On a debian buster x64 host, I have created a VM (based on QEMU). The VM runs on a block device partition, let's say `/dev/sdc1`. I have installed the debian system on that partition basically like that (some steps omitted):

```
#> mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/sdc1
#> mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/target
#> debootstrap ... bullseye /mnt/target
```

Then I bind-mounted the necessary directories (`/dev`, `/sys` etc.), chrooted into `/mnt/target`, completed the guest OS installation and booted the VM.

The VM first started without issues. But with every VM reboot, the VM got more problems, which I was repairing at the `GRUB` and `initramfs` prompts, until repairing was not possible any more because obviously the `ext4` file system had been damaged.

Because I originally thought that I had done something wrong, e.g. forgot to unmount the `ext4` partition before starting the VM, I repeated the whole installation from scratch multiple times. The result was the same in every case: After a few restarts, the `ext4` file system was so damaged that I couldn't repair it.

Accidentally, I have found the reason for this, but have no idea how to solve the problem. I noticed that `e2fsck` refused to operate on that partition, claiming that is was in use although it was not mounted and the VM was not running. Further investigation showed that there existed a kernel thread `jbd2/sdc`.

That means that the **host** kernel accesses the journal on that partition / file system. When I start the VM, the **guest** kernel of course does the same. I am nearly sure that the corruption of the file system is due to both kernels accessing the file system, notably the journal, at the same time.

How can I solve the problem?

I cannot blacklist the respective disk or the respective partition on the host, because I need to mount them there to prepare or complete the guest OS installation in a chroot. On the other hand, it doesn't seem possible to tell the host kernel to release the journal as soon as the VM starts.

I have installed a lot of VMs in the past years exactly the same way, but did not turn on the journal when creating their `ext4` file system. Consequently, I didn't have that issue with those VMs.

**Edit 1**

In case it is relevant, when mounting the partition and chrooting into it to complete the guest OS installation, I use the following commands:

```
cd /mnt
mkdir target

mount /dev/sdc1 target

mount --rbind /dev target/dev
mount --make-rslave target/dev
mount --rbind /proc target/proc
mount --make-rslave target/proc
mount --rbind /sys target/sys
mount --make-rslave target/sys

LANG=C.UTF-8 chroot target /bin/bash --login
```

When unmounting, I just do

```
umount -R target
```

The `umount` command does not report any error.

Comment: Pass `-o norecovery` to mount ?

Comment: After installation, make sure to exit chroot, umount the partition you installed the guest OS on and then start QEMU. There is no need for it to be mounted on host *after* you finish installation.

Comment: Of course, I exited the chroot and unmounted the partition before starting the VM. The problem is that the host kernel nevertheless puts its hands on the journal. Therefore, I even can't do `e2fsck` on that partition *after* having it unmounted. I even can't create a new `ext4` file system on that partition *after* having it unmounted!

Comment: Or just bin the journal altogether?  `tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdXY`

Comment: Did the umount command give any errors? Basically, what you described shouldn't happen if the partition was successfully unmounted.

Comment: @steve Thanks for your suggestions. The first one looks promising. However, I am still asking myself why the host kernel grabs that journal even after having dismounted the partition. I don't want to dump the journal completely, though. I'll try your first suggestion and report back.

Comment: Also, run `e2fsck -p /dev/sdc1`, where /dev/sdc1 is the guest's partition, on the host when it is not mounted and not used by QEMU.

Comment: @Vilinkameni The weird thing is that `umount` did not give any errors. Maybe the problem is due to the rbinds? I'll update my question to show them exactly.

Comment: @Vilinkameni The problem is that I can't even run `e2fsck` on that partition because `e2fsck` claims that it is in use *after* unmounting it. That was what put me on the right track regarding the cause of the problem ...

Comment: You can try using lsof(1) to find out what process is using specific files.

Comment: Yes, as described in my post, I did find out that there is a **host** kernel thread `jbd2/sdc` even after the file system has been dismounted; I was using `lsof` to find that out. This means that the host kernel accesses the journal of that ext4 file system even after it has been unmounted.

Comment: Is there a reason why `--rbind` and `--make-rslave` and double calls of mount for each mountpoint are necessary instead of single mount calls per mountpoint with a simple `-B`? That might be causing the issue.

Comment: Also the comments in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437025/367454) seem to suggest this might be a kernel bug or related to mount namespaces. What does the /proc/self/mountinfo show?

Comment: @Vilinkameni `mount` as well as `/proc/self/mountinfo` as well as `/proc/self/mounts` did not output / contain an entry relating to the partition or directory in question. Neither did `lsof` or `fuser`. I believe that I am a victim of that kernel bug. debian buster comes with 4.19 with debian patches.

Comment: @Vilinkameni There are multiple reasons to not use `mount -B`: It does not not bind recursively, and nowadays it does a shared bind (instead of the usual private bind) due to some changes in `systemd`, which is fatal in use cases like the one described above. For more information, see https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Known_Issues_and_Workarounds

Comment: @steve Your first suggestion seems to have mitigated the problem. Thank you very much! When I consequently use `-o norecovery`, the host kernel does not put its hands on the `ext4` partition's journal, and there are no `jbd2/sdc` entries any more in the output of `lsof`. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. Besides that, I guess that the debian kernel is buggy: I still even can't `e2fsck` that partitions as soon as I have mounted and unmounted it, but at least it doesn't damage the file system any more.

Comment: why do you think you need to install debian in a **VM** using debootstrap?   it's better AND easier to just install from a CD/DVD image .iso file.   debootstrap's fine for a chroot or container, but a VM should have a proper install just like a physical machine.

Comment: @cas I am not sure whether the sort of installation you propose wouldn't produce the same problem. But thanks for the tip, I'll try it out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `-o norecovery` to `mount`, you could mount the filesystem without making use of the journal at all.

Man page for [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount), ext3 section:

> norecovery/noload
>
> Don't load the journal on mounting. Note that if the filesystem was not unmounted cleanly, skipping the journal replay will lead to the filesystem containing inconsistencies that can lead to any number of problems.

Comment: OK, thanks, that solved the problem, accepted and +1.